# scilinux6 (rhel6) perl pathing question

Tags: perl, rhel6

Working on SL6.

[CODE]
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Scientific Linux release 6.0 (Carbon)
$ uname -an
Linux bigbox.em.local 2.6.32-131.6.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 12 17:14:50 CDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

what's the proper way to resolve the following:

CODE
$ perl Build.PL
Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Build.PL line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 4.

I have discovered the following:

CODE

$ rpm -qa|grep Build
perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.27-119.el6.x86_64
perl-Module-Build-0.3607-1.el5.rf.noarch

so it looks like it's there.

CODE

$ sudo updatedb
$ locate Build.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Module/Build.pm

Which doesn't look like it's in the @INC. I could either do a symlink, or just put 5.8.8 in the $INC, but then that would screw up any future updating, not to mention whatever else it'll break.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Module::Build package is from 'el5' meaning Scientific Linux version 5.0, it belongs to an older version of Scientific Linux and Perl: 5.8.x whereas SL6 has Perl 5.10.x.

Please check if you can install a recent version from the repositories:

```
yum install 'perl(Module::Build)'
```

if that does not work you might need to check into the repository configuration on your system.
After this you'll have the version installed, in your path, as you'd expect.

Comment: OK, that seemed to work.  Is  the yum install 'perl(whatever::whatever)'  the new improved way of doing perl modules in RH stuff now?

Comment: Since this was a fresh install (as of a couple of weeks ago) should I change something to make the pathing correct?  or at least make things load correctly?

Comment: sorry, I meant make the -install- correctly, that is, use EL6 repos rather than try to install EL5 perl

Comment: Well, sometimes modules that are called Some::Name are provided in a package which is called perl-Different-Name - but all packages at least expose 'virtual packages' that you can install to make this easier. Therefore I prefer to use the 'perl(Some::Name)' format because that always works.

Comment: In case you made a fresh install of SL6 you really should not expect to find EL5 packages on your system. Please double check your yum sources configuration, and if needed, file a bug about this.

Comment: Just to update and bring some sort of closure on this, I had to take the decision that I don't have the time or the desire to do a full reinstall given the difficulties and uncertainties, so I decided to send the drive with my old Centos53 out to be recovered and I'll continue to use that.  I think that'll be cheaper and faster in the long run, and I can get back to my real job.  Which my boss will like.