# SciLinux6 perl Test::Trap and Tk installation...how?

Tags: perl, rhel6

A more or less fresh install of SciLinux 6:

[CODE] $ cat /etc/redhat-release Scientific Linux release 6.0 (Carbon) $ uname -an Linux bigbox.em.local 2.6.32-131.6.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 12 17:14:50 CDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[/CODE]

I'm trying to install a great little package called ClusterSSH:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page

http://search.cpan.org/~duncs/App-ClusterSSH-4.00_06/bin/ctel

Apparently EL6 yum keeps wanting to install perl modules from EL5.5, so, from:

[scilinux6 (rhel6) perl pathing question](https://serverfault.com/questions/300349/scilinux6-rhel6-perl-pathing-question)

have to do something different than I've gotten used to doing, namely:

```
# yum install 'perl(something::something)'
```

So, here's the problem:

```
# perl Build.PL
Checking whether your kit is complete...
Looks good

Checking prerequisites...
 - ERROR: Test::Trap is not installed
 - ERROR: Tk is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to  install the versions
```

of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

```
Deleting Build
Removed previous script 'Build'

Creating new 'Build' script for 'App-ClusterSSH'     version     '4.00_11'

# sudo yum install 'perl(Test::Trap)'
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package perl(Test::Trap) available.
Error: Nothing to do

# rpm -qa |grep Tk
perl-Tk-804.029-1.el5.rf.x86_64
```

note the el5 suffix...grrr

```
# sudo yum install 'perl(Tk)'
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package perl(Tk) available.
Error: Nothing to do

# sudo yum install 'perl(perl::Tk)'
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package perl(perl::Tk) available.
Error: Nothing to do

# sudo yum install 'perl(Perl::Tk)'
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package perl(Perl::Tk) available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So what do I do now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `rpm -qa | grep Tk`, `perl-Tk` is installed on your system. You can install `Test::Trap` module by using CPAN method:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Test::Trap
```

or download the source code and manually install:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/E/EB/EBHANSSEN/Test-Trap-v0.2.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf Test-Trap-v0.2.1.tar.gz
cd Test-Trap-v0.2.1
perl Makefile.PL
make
make install
```

Comment: Well, I could do that.  But RuleOne that was pounded in from Very Early Days was neverevereverever install anything outside the yum system because if you do then that plants dependency and version-compatibility time bombs.        I did sort of cheat in times past by using checkinstall, but nowadays that's barfing as well.

Comment: All, thanks for trying, but with all the other problems that have come up with this 'fresh' install, I gave up and sent the old centos5 hard drive out to be recovered.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is really an issue with the package setup on your Scientific Linux system. I have a 6.1 machine where it works 'as expected'.

Your RPM output marks the package as installed, but it's from el5 meaning for perl 5.8.x so your system perl (5.10.x) can't find it.

Apparently there is no packaged Tk module in your repos. You can either fix this by adding more repos (EPEL or RPMForge), in the hope they have the modules you need, or installing everything from CPAN. 
For compiling the perl Tk module you'll need the tk-devel libs (or something similar). These you should be able to find via yum.

If you install modules from CPAN you usually should just run

```
cpan Test::Trap
cpan Tk
```

Please note that cpanminus is a very popular alternative (more clean) cpan client nowadays. Setting that up would also be possible.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, is that somehow, for some reason, there is an Issue with the package repo on this machine.  So I think the better approach is to fix -that- problem.  But how?  My other, basically irrelevant, question is "how did this happen on a fresh install?".  Thoughts on how to fix?  Or do I just need to do a reformat/reinstall?  *shudder*

Comment: Just check the manual for the repo configuration:
[Configuring Yum](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html)